# populate a field in form B from form A using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, frontend

I am new to Angular and trying to achieve this following situation.
lets say I have a form A in formA.html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
     <span class="col-sm-12">Statement1: </span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label> Statements </mat-label>
      <textarea spellcheck="true" matInput placeholder="" formControlName="case1" cols="100" rows="10"</textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

and now I have formB in formB.html, and I want the comments field to be populated with the statement1 value from form A. how can I achieve this?

```
  <div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3">
     <span class="col-sm-12">comments: </span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-sm-9">
      <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" appearance="outline">
      <mat-label> comment# </mat-label>
      <textarea spellcheck="true" matInput placeholder="" formControlName="comments" cols="100" rows="10">  this has to be the value thats in form A statement 1 field.</textarea>
      </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular 1 Component should only have 1 html file. Which means there are other things to consinder in your questions like, how are those components related.

You are using reactive forms, so i will describe an example with reactive forms.

Im just going to consider, that you have 2 completly different components.
So what you would want to do in your first component (where the data is put in)
is that you listen to your valueChanges() of the form. Take that value and safe it into a Service, and get the data from your Service in your second component.

```
this.form.valueChanges.subscribe((data) => {
// some BehaviorSubject or Observable will get the data int
 this.service.subject.next(data)...
})
```

The valueChanges Property exists on the whole form and on specific formControls.
In your second component you would subscribe to the subject and react to the value change.

```
this.service.subject.subscribe((data) =>  this.form.controls['somevalue']).setValue(data);
```

and thats it.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, could you please provide an example that suits my use case as I am new to angular.